# How can I see the additional information about differences between two arrays, list or other collections in Java?

Tags: java

I want to compare two arrays of exactly the same size, but storing values of different types. Suppose very simple example:

Array1:

- HashMap,
- List of HashMap

Array2:

- HashMap,
- HashMap

When I use methods such us `equals` or `contains`, they provide me a Boolean value `false`. 
Is there any built-in method in Java that could print also which objects differs - their values, types and other additional information?
For example: `second element of Array2 is of different type`?

Comment: a List does not have a `key`, so what are you trying to compare?

Comment: I'm trying to compare their values. Regarding my question, I'm searching for a method that will instruct me in something like that: Arrays1, element 2 and Arrays2$ element 2 are of different types or give me any hint. My example here is trivial, but suppose I have an array with 100 elements...

Comment: so have you got the [values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values--)

Comment: No, you'll have to iterate the array yourself and extract the information you need. It's trivial enough and to dependent on what your requirements are to be in the standard library, it's really just a single loop and a method call for each index.

Comment: Could you please clarify your exact requirements? *"Additional information"* is a little vague to me.